# How to access multiple MQ server endpoints from one Java client

Tags: ibm-mq

I would like my Java MQ client to be able to access (do puts) to multiple MQ server endpoints (by endpoint i mean 'host/port/Qmanager/Queue/Channel'). Basically this Java app will get a request to put a message and the endpoint detail along with the request. It should be able to find the corresponding connection pool for the endpoint and use it to do the put.
From my limited understanding so far, the MQEnvironment is a global configuration (only one is possible in one JVM?) which can be configured to one endpoint at a time. So if the idea is multiple threads accessing multiple MQserver endpoints parallely - this does not seem to implementable with current understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a Hashtable to pass connection parameters while creating a connection to queue manager. For example:

```
  Hashtable<String, Object> properties;
  properties = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
  properties.put("hostname", "remotehost");
  properties.put("port", new Integer(1414));
  properties.put("channel", "REMOTEQM.SVRCONN");
  MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shashi, your suggestion of storing Hashtable key-value pairs and passing it to QMqnager constructor - worked! One follow up question : In case of multiple threads creating their own Hashtable for QManager and using it, how does connection pooling work? Can there be a Endpoint specific ConnectionManager which is passed to QManager constructor (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031140_.htm) Appreciate any comments/pointers.

Comment: MQ Java client does not provide connection pooling. You will need implement connection pooling. Connection pooling functionality is typically implemented by J2EE containers. It's worth considering the solution suggested by @Roger below if queue manager interconnection is a possibility for you.

Comment: I see an implementation of com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager and sample here : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031140_.htm. And am planning to use it, but was not sure how this would work in Multi endpoint scenario, (since the connection pool now would require to be Endpoint specific) as discussed above. Am i missing something ? Threadpool can be taken care by J2EE container or custom.

Comment: Conection pooling is surely supported by MQ Classes for Java in version 7.5. I beleive it was added even before. It wasn't present in version 6.x

Comment: Found and validated that @Shashi's solution works not only for custom properties but for custom connection pooling also. In the sense, different connection pools can be passed to different "new MQManager(..)" calls and they all work concurrently. Thanks Shashi for understanding the question perfectly and suggesting the right solution :) .

Answer (score 2):

Either you don't understand MQ very well or your MQ environment is not set up correctly.

Your MQ application should be connecting (and stay connected) to a single queue manager.  The queue managers in your MQ environment should be interconnected such that when your MQ application puts a message destined for another queue manager, the local queue manager (that your application is connected to) will route the message to the correct queue manager.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I guess I need to clarify my requirement a bit more. The messages are not meant to be broadcasted to multiple queues. But each message has a unique queue endpoint as destination and the Java application has to route the message to the correct queue endpoint.

Comment: I NEVER said anything about 'broadcast' (or Pub/Sub).  My comment was about point-to-point messaging.  You appear to be creating a mini message broker application and that is fine but you need MORE training on how MQ works or how other people use MQ.  Lets say you are sending messages to 5 different queues on different queue managers.  You do NOT connect to each queue manager but rather connect each queue manager together with sender/receiver channels.  Hence, your application connects to ONLY one queue manager and it will route the message to the correct queue manager.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your point @Roger, i agree and it makes sense to have the queue managers connected in this scenario. However my scenario is different in the sense : one message M1 is not being sent to QM1, QM2, QM3 etc. rather, M1 is to be sent to QM1, M2 is to be sent to QM2, M3 is to be sent to QM3 and these can be happening in parallel. One message is to be sent to only one QM. Trying to clarify my earlier posts. In the scenario where the same message is to be sent to different QMs i agree with your solution that the QMs can be connected, i was not aware that could be done. Thanks.

Comment: OMG.  What is your fixation on sending duplicate messages?!?!? (given I have never mentioned it)  You really, REALLY don't know MQ or even understand my responses.  Example: Q1 (queue) is on QMA (queue manger), Q2 is on QMB, Q3 is on QMC,  Lets say your application is connecting to queue manager QMD.  First, you or your MQAdmin interconnects the queue managers with sender/receiver channels:  QMD <-> QMA, QMD <-> QMB, QMD <-> QMC.  Now, when your application (connected to QMD) puts a M1 (message), QMD will route it to Q1 on MQA and when you put M2 (message), QMD will route it to Q2 on MQB, etc.

Comment: Hence, your application connects ONLY to ONE queue manager, QMD, and it will route messages M1, M2, etc. to the correct queue on a particular queue manager (NO message duplication or Pub/Sub).  What is so hard to understand?????

Comment: Finally, do you understand the concept of a 'remote queue' in MQ? From the MQ Knowledge Center:  'remote queue is a definition on a local queue manager that refers to a queue on a remote queue manager.'   Please read: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q021210_.htm